# pop up modal is not submitting and not going to controller action url?

Tags: database, controllers, popup, submit-form

```
<?php
/**

/** @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View */
?>
<?php $_product = $block->getProduct(); ?>
<?php $buttonTitle = __('Add to Cart'); ?>
<?php $isSaleable = $_product->isSaleable();?>
<?php if($_product->getFinalPrice() > 0){ ?>
<div class="box-tocart">
    <div class="fieldset">
        <?php if ($block->shouldRenderQuantity()): ?>
        <div class="field qty">
            <label class="label" for="qty"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Qty') ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input type="number"
                       name="qty"
                       id="qty"
                       value="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>"
                       title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Qty') ?>"
                       class="input-text qty"
                       data-validate="<?= $block->escapeHtml(json_encode($block->getQuantityValidators())) ?>"
                       />
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <div class="actions">
            <button type="submit"
                    title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $buttonTitle ?>"
                    class="action primary tocart"
                    id="product-addtocart-button" <?php echo ($_product->isVirtual() && $isSaleable)?'':'disabled'; ;?>>
                <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $buttonTitle ?></span>
            </button>
            <?php if($isSaleable):?>
                <?= $block->getChildHtml('', true) ?>
            <?php endif;?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php if ($block->isRedirectToCartEnabled()) : ?>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#product_addtocart_form": {
            "Magento_Catalog/product/view/validation": {
                "radioCheckboxClosest": ".nested"
            }
        }
    }
</script>
<?php else : ?>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#product_addtocart_form": {
            "Magento_Catalog/js/validate-product": {}
        }
    }
</script>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php } else{ ?>

<?php 
$erHelper = $this->helper('Eaglerocket\Customquote\Helper\Data');
$questions = $erHelper->getQuestions();
 ?>
  <div class="box-tocart">
      <div class="fieldset">
        <div class="actions">
          <button type="button" class="action primary tocart btn btn-primary btn-lg" id="popupButton" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><?php echo __('Quote')?></button>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Modal $question->getQuestion()-->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog" style="display:none;">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <!-- Modal content data-validate="{required:true}" aria-required="true"-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title"><?php echo __('Get Quote')?></h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <form  method="post" action="<?php echo $block->getBaseUrl() ?>" >
            <fieldset class="fieldset">
              <?php foreach ($questions as $question) { ?>
                <div class="field comment required">
                    <div class="control">
                        <textarea name="comment"  title="<?php echo $question->getQuestion() ?>" placeholder="<?php echo $question->getQuestion() ?>" class="input-text" cols="5" rows="3"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
              <?php } ?>
              <div class="field comment required">
                    <div class="control">
                        <textarea name="email" id="email" title="<?php echo ('Email') ?>" 
                            placeholder="('customquote/index/index') " 
                            class="input-text" cols="5" rows="3" data-validate="{required:true}" aria-required="true">
                            </textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
<!--             <div class="actions-toolbar">-->  
    <div>
             <div class="primary">
<!--                   <input type="hidden" name="hideit" id="hideit" value="">
 -->                  <button type="submit" title="Submit">
                      <span>Submit</span>
                  </button>
              </div>
            </div>

          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<script>
 
require(
        [
            'jquery',
            'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
        ],
        function(
            $,
            modal
        ) {
            var options = {
                type: 'popup',
                responsive: true,
                innerScroll: true,
                 
               
                buttons: [{
                    text: $.mage.__('Continue'),
                    class: 'mymodal1',
                    click: function () {
                        this.closeModal();
                    }
                }]
             };
            var popup = modal(options, $('#myModal'));
            $("#popupButton").on('click',function(){
                $("#myModal").modal("openModal");
            });
        
});

  </script>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this first you have model popup and below that you have your ajax call

```
    <div class="callfor-popup">
       <h2>Simple Modal</h2>
    </div>
    <script>
       require(['jquery','Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'],
        function ($,modal) {
               var modaloption = {
                   type: 'popup',
                   modalClass: 'modal-popup',
                   responsive: true,
                   innerScroll: true,
                   clickableOverlay: true,
                   title: 'Simple Modal'
               };
               modal(modaloption, $('.callfor-popup'));
               $('.callfor-popup').modal('openModal');
           }

//change class name to model popup "ok" button class name
           $(".yourButtonClass").on('click', function(event){
                var base_url = window.location.origin;
                var customurl = base_url + "/sampleorder/sampleorder/search";
                $.ajax({
                    url: customurl,
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: {
                        customdata1: 'test1',
                        customdata2: 'test2',
                    },
                complete: function(response) {             
                   // country = response.responseJSON.default_country;
                   // state = response.responseJSON.state;         
                   // console.log(state+' '+country);   
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, status, errorThrown) {
                        console.log('Error happens. Try again.');
                    }
                });
            });
       );
    </script>
```

upvote if helps